# I am having trouble making a simple POST Request

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api

I am trying to do a simple call to an API endpoint using the following code and keep getting the following error:

> POST net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

The request options

```
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    };
```

The fetch request

```
            await fetch("https://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/scripts/user-login.php", requestOptions)
                .then(async response => await response.text())
                .then(response => response === "" ? {} : JSON.parse(response) )
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                })
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Edit: I was only provided with the following documentation:

> a. When the form has been successfully submitted passing all
> validation errors, call the following API:
> http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/scripts/user-login.php i. This API
> endpoint needs to be called with a POST request. ii. It takes two body
> params: email and password. iii. For testing purposes, use the
> following email and password: test@rapptrlabs.com / Test123. iv. A
> successful response will look like the following:
>
> { "user_id": 16,
> "user_email": "test@rapptrlabs.com",
> "user_username": "testuser",
> "user_is_active": 1,
> "user_profile_image": "http://dev.rapptrlabs.com/Tests/images/taylor_avatar.png",
> "user_last_active_epoch": 1544680026,
> "user_creation_epoch": 1544713200,
> "user_is_new": 1,
> "user_token": "6dd4737a8b7ec61313ae5e900420d46815e1d13b2902be71b97a8fbf1f421a3e" }

Edit: This issue is resolved now. The issue was that I had to use a form tag to submit the fetch request. And I have to use FormData as the request option of the fetch request.

Comment: Probably it's the Content-Type (i.e May not want `application/json`), but could be missing headers or a number of other things.  You have not provided documentation for the endpoint you're using so it's hard to tell.

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors',` is used when you do not want to see any response at all from a cross origin request - is this a cross origin request or a same origin request? - oh, wait, you wouldn't own rapptr labs ... so, yeah, you've guaranteed there will be no response to your request

Comment: also (not the problem) - use `async`/`await` OR `.then` - and definitely not `.then(async response => await response.text())` ... that's just `.then(response => response.text())` anyway

Comment: Isn't this an error raised by the backend because the post body/content type doesn't match what it is expected?

Comment: @user3252327 maybe.  The backend should/could respond with a 415 for using the wrong content type, but there's many backends that will just return a 400

Comment: If the backend is in your control/code base, I would start by debugging/checking the logs in the backend rather than the frontend

Comment: @Jaromanda X: I wrote mode: "no-cors" because originally I was getting an error about how the fetch " has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Comment: You need to read error messages carefully. It only says to use `mode: 'no-cors'` if an opaque response serves your needs. Your next step should have been determining if that was the case by looking up what an _"opaque response"_ means

Comment: `mode: no-cors` is NOT how you *get around CORS* - unless you don't care about the response of course - but, in this case, I think you DO care about the response ... the only way to *get around CORS* is to make the request from *your server*, not the browser

Comment: The documentation says "when the form has been successfully submitted", which could imply that the backend is literally expecting a form.  (i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)

Comment: @JaromandaX `no-cors` also affects the request by requiring / enforcing [simple headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header). Even if OP didn't care about the response, they still can't use it to send JSON

Comment: @Phil - to be honest I didn't even look at what the OP is requesting after I saw the attempted CORS buster `no-cors` :p

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks. Your idea was the right answer. I had to use a form tag to submit the fetch request. And I have to use FormData as request option of the fetch request.

Comment: `let fd = new FormData(); fd.append("email", email"); fd.append("password", password); const requestOptions = { method: 'POST', ... body: fd }` (Shouldn't need to specify content type, but it's been a while)